# openCV RGB2Gray with custom weights

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

The color to grayscale algorithm is stated in the cvtColor() documentation. (search for RGB2GRAY).

Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B

I am using

```
    cv::Mat i_test_base;
    cv::cvtColor(white_balance_image, i_test_base, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::imshow("cvtColor", i_test_base);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

I'm working with Macbeth chart and it can result too low signal level when detecting e.g. blue patch. Using just sum between channels or max of  the RGB values would most likely work better.

I tried something like

```
cv::transform(white_balance_image, i_test_base, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));
cv::imshow("transform", i_test_base);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

but this doesn't work, I get a white image.
do I need to scale or something like that?

Comment: Can you post a sample input image? The current weights will end up saturating for 2/3 of the input colors. Perhaps working with the V channel of an HSV image might yield better results?

Comment: @DanMašek I can post the input image, but this is just a regular macbeth chart, nothing special. just want to know if there is a way to put different weights.

Comment: If you convert to a float you can work with the images without worrying about saturation/overflow with normal `uint8` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `cv::transform`, make sure that the weights sum to 1 (or less) to avoid saturation.

If you use

```
cv::transform(white_balance_image, i_test_base, cv::Matx13f(0.114, 0.587, 0.299));
```

on a BGR image you should get the same as `BGR2GRAY`. If you use `(1/3.0, 1/3.0, 1/3.0)` instead, you should get an average of the 3 channels. Adjust to your liking.